# updating a field with sum of fields in another table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I'm having great difficulty in finding how to do this. I've been searching for hours but can't come up with a working solution.

I have two tables.

```
TableA - Code, TranDate, Amount

TableB - Code Amount
```

I wish to Update TableB Amount by deducting the sum of Amount in TableA (where a.code = b.code
and a.TranDate > 'A GIVEN DATE'

I have to confess to having limited ability with SQL. I am using SQL server 2005.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easy way with Common Table Extensions:

```
with cte as (
   select A.Code, sum( A.Amount ) as Amount
   from TableA A inner join TableB B on A.Code = B.Code 
   where A.TranDate > *someDete*
   Group by A.Code
)
update B
Set B.amount = CTE.amount
from TableB B inner join CTE on B.Code = CTE.Code
```

**Edited** Due OP comment:

CTE is available from sqlserver 2005: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766(v=sql.90).aspx

Query is tested on sqlserver 2008: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9e424/1/0

Comment: Thanks for the response. 
I am getting 'incorrect syntax near the keyword 'from'. 

my test code is :

with cte as (
  select a.code, sum((a.amount) as [amount]
  from nominald a inner join trial B on a.code = b.code
  where a.trandate > '2012-08-13'
  group by a.code
  )

update b
set b.balance = cte.amount
from trial b inner join cte on b.code = cte.code

Comment: Many thanks!

Having removed the extra opening bracket Syntax resolved.
Solution needed a tweak. For some reason i had to explicitly specify B as the actual table name in the final update statement.

Final coding (working)

with cte as (
  select a.code, sum(a.amount) as amount
  from nominald a inner join trial B on a.code = b.code
  where a.trandate > '2012-08-13'
  group by a.code
  )

update trial
set trial.balance = trial.balance - cte.amount
from trial inner join cte on trial.code = cte.code

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
@Date = 'A GIVEN DATE'
UPDATE TableB 
     SET TableB.Amount = TableB.Amount - (SELECT SUM(TableA.Amount) 
                                   FROM TableA as A, TableB 
                                   WHERE A.Code = B.Code AND A.TranDate > @Date)
```

Comment: Thanks for the response.I have given this a try. What is happening which has been my main problem all along is that all the records in TableB are updated with the same amount.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
UPDATE TB 
SET
    TB.Amount = TB.Amount - TotalDeduction
FROM TableB TB
JOIN (SELECT Code, SUM(Amount) AS TotalDeduction FROM TableA GROUP BY Code) TA ON TA.Code = TB.Code
```

Comment: Thanks for the response.

Couldn't get this to work. Amount appears to get updated with multiple values and update affecting all the records in the table.

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @date date,
update TableB
set TableB.Amount= TableB.Amount-sum(TableA.Amount) from TableA, TableB
where TableA.code = TableB.code and TableA.TranDate >@date
```

Comment: Thanks for the response.

Solution failed with 'aggregate may not appear in the set list of an UPDATE statement